# Arc length of quadratic curve

Tags: definite-integrals, quadratics, arc-length

I would like to find the arc length of a curve from $a\le t\le b$, the curve is $t^2A+tB+C$ $$arcLength=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{(2At+B)^2+1}\,dt$$
I am having trouble getting rid of $t$ (the variable) (variables $A$, $B$, $a$, $b$, and $C$ are constants)
I need help solving the above integral to get the arc length

## Thanks in Advanced

Answer (score 1):

More a comment than answer,
but easier to enter as an answer.

Wolfy gives four forms
for the indefinite integral,
one of which is

$\dfrac{\sqrt{(2 A t + B)^2 + 1} (2 A t + B) + \sinh^{-1}(2 A t + B)}{4 A} + constant
$

Comment: That can be found with the hyperbolic substitution $2At+B=\tan\theta$. If you know your hyperbolic identities, it's easier to deal with than the trig substitution.

Comment: Looks like a trig substitution.

Comment: Oops - I meant $\sinh$ instead of $\tan$ there.

Comment: Can I use this as an antiderivative F, and do F(a)-F(b) to get the arc length? thank you. I will test it out

Comment: That's the usual way when the integration interval has variable endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

It's already in a good form. The next step, with the standard techniques? A trig substitution $2At+B=\tan\theta$.